# Standard pixel density for print?

Tags: gimp, dpi

I have to design a flyer for half of an 8<sup>1/2</sup> x 11 page. It mostly has images but some text. And I'm designing it in GIMP. Is there an industry standard dpi for simple prints? It's not magazine quality, but I'm looking for a decent dpi.

Comment: 300 dpi, 600 if it has fine detail

Answer (score 2):

300ppi is industry standard for normal print items. [Difference between PPI and DPI](http://www.imagescience.com.au/kb/questions/31/The+difference+between+PPI+and+DPI)

How many actual pixels you have in your artwork is what is important, so you need (300 x width in inches) by (300 x height in inches)